# shree ganaadheesha stotram

Tags: ganesha, stotra

It is possible to have a translation of this [Stotram](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_ganesha/shivashaktikRitaMgaNAdhIshastotram.html?lang=sa) ?

In the menu on the top right there many variants but of course is not translated, only translitterated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the needed translation from [this page](http://www.stutimandal.com/poemgen.php?id=250).

The Stotram in the question starts with the verse:

> नमस्ते गणनाथाय गणानां पतये नमः ।
>  भक्तिप्रियाय देवेश भक्तेभ्यः
> सुखदायक ॥ १॥
>
> Namaste gananathaya gananam pataye namah |
>  Bhaktipriyaya devesha
> bhaktebhyah sukhadayaka ||

The Stotram I am giving the translation of also starts with the same verse. And, it can be easily verified that both are the same Stotram (which was composed/told by Shiva-Shakti)

Quoting the translation:

> **Śivaśaktikṛtagaṇādhīśastotram**
>
> O [[Ga.ne"sa]], Who is the Lord of demi-gods, and Who bestows bliss to
> devotees! Salutations for You, Who is the leader of [[Ga.na]], Who is
> the Lord of various [[Ga.na]], and Who likes devotion.[1](http://www.stutimandal.com/poemgen.php?id=250) Salutations
> for You, Who is rejoicing in His own bliss, Who is the most skilled
> ([[siddha]]) and most wise ([[buddhi]]) among all, Who has
> [["se.sanaaga]] (serpent) tied at the belly, Who is noble, and Who is
> [[.Dhu.n.dhiraaja]].[2]
>
> Salutations for You, Who has the [[vara]] and [[abhaya mudraa]] in
> hands, Who holds an axe, Who holds a sickle, and Who has
> [["se.sanaaga]] (serpent) tied at the belly.[3] Salutations for You,
> Who is free from disease ([[bhavaroga]]), Who is of all sorts, Who is
> worthy of worship by everyone, Who is with form and quality (as
> [[Ga.ne"sa]]), and Who is formless and qualityless as [[Brahman]].[4]
>
> O [[Ga.ne"sa]], Who has a head of an elephant! May salutations be for
> You, and Who gives the position of [[Brahmaa]] to the creators of the
> world. Salutations for You, Who is worshipped in the beginning, Who is
> the elder (son of [[Paarvatii]]), and Who is the most eminent.[5]
> Salutations again and again for everyone’s [[Heramba]], Who is the
> Mother and the Father. O [[Ga.ne"sa]], Who rules over obstacles!
> Salutations again and again for You, Who is without a beginning, and
> Who (may) put obstacles.[6]
>
> O [[Lambodara]]! May salutations be for You, Who destroys obstacles of
> His own devotees. By Your devotion, many [[Yogii]] have reached the
> state of inner peace and bliss.[7] How to eulogize about You, Who is
> the essence of [[Yoga]]! We (both) salute You, Who absolves obstacles.
> O Lord (owner)! May You become satisfied by this eulogy. Having said
> thus, they saluted Him ([[Ga.ne"sa]]).[8]
>
> Having put His hands on them, [[Ga.naadhii"sa]] spoke thus to those
> great [[I"svara]] ([["Siva]] and [["Sakti]]). [["Sriiga.ne"sa]] spoke:
> This eulogy, Which is created by You, will increase devotion of me.
> Also, it will bestow friendship of mine, if it is studied and listened
> regularly. By the reciter (or listener), everything -- including
> luxuries and salvation, sons and grandsons, and food or grains -- will
> be obtained; it is sure.[10]

The translation was submitted by some Animesh Kumar.

Comment: Good finding!..the source you quoted seems to be very useful..

Comment: Thanks and yes I too felt exactly the same about that site (it is a very useful site). It is usually difficult to find the translation of the given Stotram. For example, you can not find it on Hindupedia @YDS

Comment: excellent, thank you!